# wicket 1.5 end of life

Tags: security, wicket, maintenance-plan

I am trying to find authoritative answer to the following questions:

> Is Wicket 1.5.10 the last release there will be and are security fixes being downported to the 1.15 code branch?

On the official distribution site I see there are no new releases of the 1.5 version since Feb.2013 and I can't find anywhere on the Wicket web site statement that clarifies the maintenance plans or policy for the 1.5 version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Additional info: Wicket 1.5 will be supported until Wicket 7.0.3/4 according to a [post from Martin Grigorov on Wicket's Mailing list](http://apache-wicket.1842946.n4.nabble.com/Wicket-7-status-tc4659803.html#a4659903)

> So a major release has 2 years life. Actually even more because 1.5.x
>   will be supported until 7.0.3/4 before be moved to security
>   maintenance mode. At least this has been the case with the previous
>   releases.

So i think you have quite some time it will be supported in terms of secuirty.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was searching for

Answer (score 1):

On the official WICKET bugtracker (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WICKET/fixforversion/12324069) there is a release for 1.5 (1.5.11) with 33 issues currently being resolved and 3 open issues, so i would assume there will be a security release for 1.5, this is no official answer however.